# Disabled button hides header when clicked

Tags: jquery-mobile, button

I'm having a very strange issue...

When I click in a button that is disabled, the header scrolls up... (demo below)

Why this happen?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2UyZ/3/)

Here is the code:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" @TempData["DataUrl"]>
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    MyApp
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div style="height:300px">Content</div>
        <div class="controlGroupButtons" data-role="controlgroup">
            <a class="Button1" data-role="button">Marcar</a>
            <a class="Button2" data-role="button">Desmarcar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
$(".Button1, .Button2").buttonMarkup().addClass("ui-disabled");
```

Comment: Sorry I cant see any problem on Firefox or Chrome. Can you describe how can we test it in your demo?

Comment: It adds class `.ui-fixed-hidden` to the header.

Comment: @Gajotres Maybe your result panel in the JsFiddle is too big and doesn´t need to scrool... try to decrease the height of the result panel, sroll down and click on a button...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `data-tap-toggle="false"` to the header div and the problem will vanish! Because when the buttons are disabled, the click will be trigger `tap` event. Once `Tap` event is triggered, it will show/hide header.

Comment: Thanks! it solved the problem... But I don't understand why they are related... In my opinion, disabling a button should not interfere in the header. Can give me some explanation why this happen? Thanks again!

Comment: add class `.ui-disabled` to an element, add `z-index: 1` which makes all other layers come above it. Fixed headers can be toggled by default when you tab on content div. So when you click on disabled buttons, you actually trigger `Tap` event since content div has higher `z-index`. add `data-tap-toggle="false"` will stop toggling header. @amp