# Stop header footer from loosing position:fixed with click - Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, cordova-3

I'm using jquery mobile in a Cordova -3 application. A simple page with header and footer having `data-position:fixed` attribute.

```
<div data-role="page" id="myPage1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Page 1 header</h1>
    </div>


     <h1>Page 1</h1>
     <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        <h1>Page 1 Footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine. But when I'm clicking any blank part of body the header footer goes away off the screen. I think it looses `data-position:fixed` attribute. Again at that time if I click again in any blank place header footer comes back as fixed. Strange behavior. I want the header footer to be fixed no matter where I touch in screen.

You can see the problem in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6ac3/) Click in any part of the body and scroll. You will see it isn't fixed anymore with respect to screen.

Please help......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabled button hides header when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401324/disabled-button-hides-header-when-clicked)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to set data-tap-toggle to false like this:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h1>Page 1 Footer</h1>
</div>
```